# What are instantaneous code words?

Tags: coding-theory

I need help understanding what instantaneous code words are.

Example:
Design an instantaneous code of length 3,2,3,2,2

```
2 00
2 01
2 10
3 100
```

Is my solution valid?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your textbook is using [the same definitions as Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) this is not a prefix code (aka instantaneous).

- Your suggested word $10$ is a prefix  of the word $100$.
- Your code is not uniquely decodable either, because $100100$ could be parsed as $10\ 01\ 00$ as well as $100\ 100$.
- Your code does not meet the specification in the sense that you listed only a single word of length three whereas the assignment asked for two.

Hint:

- You need to use three out of four two-bit segments as codewords. This leaves relatively few possibilities for the first two bits of the three-bit codewords.